# Calculator Regular Expression with decimal point and minus sign

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html

I need a regular expression that validates the following inputs:

```
-0.12-12.56
-0.12+12.56
-0.12*12.56
-0.12/12.56
12.3--12.56
12.3+-12.56
12.3*-12.56
12.3/-12.56
-0.12--12.56
-0.12+-12.56
-0.12*-12.56
-0.12/-12.56
0.12-12.56
0.12+12.56
0.12*12.56
0.12/12.56
```

Also it should allow all this conditions  without decimal point and if decimal point is allowed then it should not be allowed more than once i.e. either between the digits or at start of an operand.

The minus sign should also be optional before the number.

Currently I am using below regular expression:

```
^-{0,1}[0-9.]+[+-×÷]{0,1}-{0,1}[0-9.]*$
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following regex:

```
/^-?\d+\.?\d+[-+*\/]-?\d+\.?\d+$/mg
```

Comment: Actually, I am watching my input field constantly and I want a validation such as when the user enters input along with that it should be validated.

Comment: You should add an event listener to user input then and check the input content against the regexp rule