# Regex to validate and extract data from a calculation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find out a regular expression where I can validate the input and also extract required information from input.

My input contains a simple calculation like addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

> For example: if input is addtion say **7.01+9.05**

```
var input = '7.01+9.05';

var pattern = /^-?\d+\.?\d+[-+*\/]-?\d+\.?\d+$/
var sign;
if (input.match(pattern)) {
    var matches = pattern.exec(input);

    var left = // logic to extract value 7.01 using matches variable;
    var right = // logic to extract value 9.05 using matches variable;
    var sing = // logic to extract symbol + using matches variable;
}
```

I have used the regular expression which I found from this post : [Calculator Regular Expression with decimal point and minus sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692265/calculator-regular-expression-with-decimal-point-and-minus-sign)

Can you please help me how to extract the required data in above code?

Comment: Using regex to parse an arithmetic expression is a generally bad idea.  You will also come to this conclusion as soon ss you have terms nested in parentheses.  Instead, I recommend writing a parser.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my requirement is for just basic things just with 2 values and a sign between them, I do not want to use nested elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern `^-?\d+\.?\d+[-+*\/]-?\d+\.?\d+$` you want to match an optional dot using `\d+\.?\d+` which works but now the minimum number of digits to match is 2 due to matching 2 times 1 or more digits using `\d+` so 1+1 would not match.

What you could do if it are only simple calculations, you could use 3 capturing groups and match a digit with an optional decimal part using `?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Your pattern might look like:

```
^(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([-+*\/])(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `([-+*\/])` Capture group 2, match any of the listed in the character class
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture group 2, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `$` End of string

See the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/8wIbOw/1)

For example

```js
var regex = /^(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([-+*\/])(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/;
[
  "21+22",
  "7.01+9.05",
  "1-1",
  "1*1",
  "0*1000000",
  "8/4"
].forEach(x => {
  var res = x.match(regex);
  var left = res[1];
  var right = res[2];
  var sing = res[3];
  console.log(left, right, sing);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `split()`

```js
var input = '7.01+9.05';

var pattern = /^-?\d+\.?\d+[-+*\/]-?\d+\.?\d+$/
if (input.match(pattern)) {
    var matches = pattern.exec(input)[0].split(/(\+|-|\*|\/)/);

    var left = matches[0];
    var right = matches[2];
    var sign = matches[1];
    console.log(left,sign,right);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to try with regular expresseions

Comment: @learner I did this using regular expressions.You want without them?

Comment: I want to know how to access data using the matches variable in my program.

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

You should define capture groups in your regex expression using `()` and `|`. It is important define a flag global to your regex to capture all groups.

There are 3 things you need to capture:

- the left number -> `^-?\d+\.?\d+`
- the sign -> `[-+*\/]`
- the right number -> `-?\d+\.?\d+$`

You should use `|` alternation to regex use the capturing groups like a or statement beetwen the groups.

The final regex will be:

```
var pattern = /(^-?\d+\.?\d+)|([-+*\/])|(-?\d+\.?\d+$)/g
```

The ouput result will be an array where the first position will be the left number, second position the sign and the third position a right number.

Therefore the rest of your code will looks like that:

```
if (input.match(pattern)) {
    var matches = input.match(pattern); \\ I recommend use input.match here too

    var left = matches[0];
    var right = matches[2];
    var sing = matches[1];
}
```

Comment: I think we need to remove "|" for the regular expression, it should be:
`^(-?\d+\.?\d+)([-+*\/])(-?\d+\.?\d+)$` ;

because
`/(^-?\d+\.?\d+)|([-+*\/])|(-?\d+\.?\d+$)/g` will match 4.05  and 4.05+9.01 and +9.01

Comment: This is not necessary because I suggest to use `input.match(pattern)`. Therefore if using `pattern.exec(input)` we shold remove the pipe `|`.